# Python index dict with different object properties

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a collection of objects in Python that share certain properties, and I want to be able to quickly look up an object based on some of them.

Are there packages that expose an API that allows you to do something like this? Or do I need to write my own?

As a more in-depth explanation, I am looking for something like this:

```
class User:
   def __init__(self, name):
      self.id = self.__hash__()
      self.name = name

mydict = AwesomeDict(keys=["name", "id"])
user1 = User("foo")
user2 = User("bar")
mydict.add(user1)
mydict.add(user2)
mydict.lookup_by("name", "foo")
# => user1

mydict.lookup_by("id", 1221332114)
# => user2
```

Comment: It is trivial to implement this yourself. There are a couple of different options available, depending on whether you're more concerned about time or space

Comment: Shortest way is just have a separate dict for each attribute you're interested in.

Comment: The api you're looking for is probably a database. It does exactly this, for large amounts of data, and very quickly (if you create indexes on the fields you want to use for lookups).

Comment: You will have to write it. No direct way in python stdlib or api.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be efficient for larger data but You can write simple function like this for small cases.

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.id = self.__hash__()
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self):
        return "(object: {} at: {})".format(self.name, self.id)


def lookup_by(mydict, look_by, key):
    for obj in mydict:
        if getattr(obj, look_by) == key:
            return obj
    return False

my_list = []
user1 = User("foo")
user2 = User("bar")

my_list.append(user1)
my_list.append(user2)
print(user2.id)
print(lookup_by(my_list, "name", "foo"))
print(lookup_by(my_list, "id", user2.id))
```

out:

```
(object: foo at: 2550687)
(object: bar at: 2550707)
```